# Can I create a Selection Rule that uses a string against a Taxonomy Term?

Tags: 7, theming, taxonomy-terms

I've got a Taxonomy Term template I wish to create a Selection rule with.

This uses a Taxonomy list as part of the content. For example, the Taxonomy list is about car makes so I have "Honda, Toyota, Mazda, Volkswagen, BMW, etc"

I want to make a selection rule where if any of the above brands are selected, it will display it's corresponding Taxonomy Term template, eg "Honda" will use the Honda Taxonomy Term template variation.

Currently, I've set this up and it works fine - In my Selection Rules I have added "Taxonomy Term car_brand" and have selected "Honda" (or whatever brand is applicable per template).

The problem is exporting these selection rules in a Feature - the database on my local is different to that on the remote server, thus my Taxonomy Term IDs (TIDs) change and the selection rules get messed up.

A solution I thought about would be to not use TIDs and use a string. However, the Taxonomy Term selection in Selection Rules only appears as a pre-populated drop down list.

Is there any way to use a textfield and string rather than select form a drop down list?

Comment: Your question seems to be about how to export your settings in Features, but your question's headline is about how to create the selection rule... please edit your question so it's clear from both what is the issue you need help with.

Comment: I know how to export my settings as features. The problem is that exporting these settings in features only captures the TID. And since I'm importing these features into another site with another database, the TIDs no longer match up. So, I'm thinking I need to convert this to strings instead.

Comment: Is the export a one-time thing or a repeating task?

Comment: You might want to look into UUID features instead of using tids. [This](https://www.drupal.org/node/1329372)  might help.